# OfficeJS -Delete and rearrange sections in a Word document

Tags: office-js

I want to delete and rearrange the sections of a Word document using `office.js`. For example, a Word document have 3 sections. And here is the list of sections headers:

1. Rocking section One
2. Rocking section Two
3. Rocking section Three

User changed it to:

1. Rocking section Three
2. Rocking section One

And finally I want to see the impact in my Word document. I can easily show user the list of headers of sections. And user can change(rearrange or delete) the list of headers. I have tried a way to do this. I changed the `items` of `sections` and tried to load the `sections`. Here is the code:

```
function RearrangeSections(sectionHeaderList) {
    Word.run(function (context) {

        var sections = context.document.sections;
        context.load(sections);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (sections != null) {                        
                    var headers = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < sections.items.length; i++) {

                        // Grab the header from the current section
                        var header = sections.items[i].getHeader('primary');

                        // Add loading this header to the  queue 
                        context.load(header);

                        // Push this header into the headers collection
                        headers.push(header);
                    }


                    var sectionItems = sections.items; //Get section items into a new list
                    context.sync().then(function () {
                        for (var i = 0; i < sectionHeaderList.length; i++) { 

                            for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                                var targetHeader = sectionHeaderList[i].name;  //
                                if (headerText == targetHeader) {
                                    context.document.sections.items[i] = sectionItems[j]; // Change the section items
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        context.load(context.document.sections); // Finally load the sections
                        return context.sync().then(function () {
                            //
                        });
                    });
                }

            }).catch(function (myError) {
                //otherwise we handle the exception here!                    
            });


    }).catch(errorHandler);

}
```

In the method parameter, `sectionHeaderList` is a list of objects which has the updated(after user change) header list. Here I just tried to rearrange.

This code do not do any thing. Am I trying in a proper way?

Thanks for reading. Any types of tip/help is welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I picked the `Ooxml` of the section bodies and then clear the document body and put the section bodies as my sequence. I used first line of the section body for matching the sections. You may use section header. That will also work.  Here is the sample code:

```
function RearrangeSections(sectionHeaderList) {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var body = context.document.body;
        var sections = context.document.sections;
        context.load(body);
        context.load(sections);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (sections != null) {
                    var itemsCount = sections.items.length;
                    var bodies = [];
                    var bodiesOoxml = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < sections.items.length; i++) {

                        var body = sections.items[i].body;
                        context.load(body);                            
                        bodies.push(body);
                    }

                    // Sync/Exectute the queued actions                       
                    var sectionItems = [];
                    sectionItems = sections.items;

                    context.sync().then(function () {
                        for (var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {
                            var ooxml = bodies[i].getOoxml();
                            bodiesOoxml.push(ooxml);
                        }


                        context.sync().then(function () {                                
                            context.document.body.clear();
                            for (var i = 0; i < sectionHeaderList.length; i++) {
                                for (var j = 0; j < bodies.length; j++) {

                                    var bodyText = bodies[j].text;
                                    var headerText = bodyText.split("\r")[0];
                                    var targetHeader = sectionHeaderList[i].name;


                                    if (headerText == targetHeader) {
                                        var val = bodiesOoxml[j].value;
                                        body.insertOoxml(val, Word.InsertLocation.end);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            context.load(context.document.sections);
                            return context.sync().then(function () {
                                console.log("Done");
                            })
                        });                            
                    }).catch(function (e) {
                        //Show error

                    });
                }

            }).catch(function (myError) {

                //Show error
            });


    }).catch(errorHandler);

}
```